# Python trapezoidal method graphing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to plot the result of a trapezoidal method into a graph, I figured out that to get the exact value of the integral you can use `integrate.trapz(f(x))` from the scypy libary. This is my second month learning comp math, not really sure about libraries usage yet.

Here is my code

```
from scipy import integrate

def f(x):
    return 1 - x - 4*x**3 + 2*x**5

def trapezoid(a, b, n):
    h = (b - a) / n
    s = (f(a) + f(b))

    i = 1
    while i < n:
        s += 2 * f(a + i * h)
        i += 1
        area = ((h / 2) * s)
    return area

def graphTrapezoid():
    val = []
    err = []
    exact_sum = integrate.trapz(f(b))-integrate.trapz(f(a))
    for i in range (2,100):
        val.append(trapezoid(a,b,i))
        errVal = abs((trapezoid(a,b,i) - exact_sum)/exact_sum)
        err.append(errVal)
    plt.plot(val, err)

a = 1
b = 5
n = 1
graphTrapezoid()
```

Below is the error statement that I got

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-504c0acc46bf> in <module>
     39 
     40 
---> 41 graphTrapezoid()

<ipython-input-134-504c0acc46bf> in graphTrapezoid()
     29     val = []
     30     err = []
---> 31     exact_sum = integrate.trapz(f(b))-integrate.trapz(f(a))
     32     for i in range (2,100):
     33         val.append(trapezoid(a,b,i))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in trapz(y, x, dx, axis)
   4059     slice1 = [slice(None)]*nd
   4060     slice2 = [slice(None)]*nd
-> 4061     slice1[axis] = slice(1, None)
   4062     slice2[axis] = slice(None, -1)
   4063     try:

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Please fix indentation in your code.

Answer (score 0):

From the scipy.integrate.trapz [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.trapz.html):

The function definition is:

```py
scipy.integrate.trapz(y, x=None, dx=1.0, axis=-1)
```

Where y should be "array_like". However, you are passing two integer values to the trapz function.

If you want to integrate `f` betweeen `b` and `a`, maybe you could first define a list of x values:

```py
a = 1
b = 5
step = 0.1 # A smaller step will give you a more precise result
x = []
for i in range(int((b-a)/step + 1)):
    x.append(a + i*step)
```

Then, sample your function:

```py
y = [f(val) for val in x]
```

And lastly, you could integrate your samples:

```py
result = integrate.trapz(y, x, dx=step)
```